# Give each message a custom delay (rabbitmq)?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I need to delay each message I produce with a specific time.
As far as I know the `rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange` plugin allows me to do exactly that, however I was warned that it doesn't scale properly which is a definite requirement. (Has there been any updates lately fixing scaling problems?)

So, the alternative was to use TTL and a DLQ. With this approach though, you set the time when creating the exchange instead of the actual message which means I wouldn't be able to set different times for different messages. 
Did I miss something?

My use case: Basicly I will be receiving specific "appointments" from clients which I must store and send back to the client at a specific time supplied in the appointment object. I want to acheive this by specifying a delay on each message so that my consumers must not implement waiting logic.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your use case?

Comment: @AlexBuyny of course, updated the question

Comment: You mentioned you don't want to implement waiting logic on the `consumer`. What about implementing waiting logic on the `producer`? It will continuously look for appointments it needs to send, and send them when time comes. Consumers receive and do their job. On the RabbitMQ side, I agree with the comments to the below answer - I don't know a way of doing it with RabbitMQ.

Comment: The main reason I've chosen RabbitMQ is because I need to give the user an instant verification that the appointment was successfully processed and at the same time make sure that it is 100% sent back after the given delay. Since rabbitmq is persistant its pretty much a perfect fit.

Comment: Im wondering if I should just give the delay plugin a try. The problem though is that they state specifically that its "not a great solution" for use cases with 100s of thousands of delayed messages which will definetly be exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a [per-queue message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html), and have different queues for each different TTL you want to set, originally publish the messages through direct exchange with key related to the specific TTL?

Then having configured the same [dead letter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for all those queues, they'll end up in the "final" queue for your consumers with the desired delay.

Of course it wouldn't be great if the possible values for the delays were too numerous.

Comment: The delays are absolutely variable, thats the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, can't see a way to do this then. Would have assumed you could have worked with 50 or so different values. Below an example for split for 17 values:
1 minute, 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 4 hours, 8 hours, 12 hours, 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, 4 days, 5 days, 6 days, 1 week, 2 weeks, 3 weeks, 4 weeks

Comment: This would be to much of a limitation to the end product as the delay is to be calculated by any time of the day. Thanks for your suggestion though! (Would you happen to know if the delay plugin has gotten support lately or works better nowadays?)

Comment: I ended up adding another db layer and stored jobs there. A 'reader' process then checks for upcoming jobs and stores them into 10 predefined queues, each a second apart. So I essentially get precision delay down to the second and can have as many as I want with a delay as long as I want